# How to make sub folder publish on Github-pages?

Tags: javascript, html, github, github-actions, github-pages

I created a repository to practice coding in HTML, CSS, Javascript. It contains about 15 exercises and each exercise stays in a folder of the repository, each of them have an index.html file. In the root of repo, I create index.html file the have 15 relative links in button tag. I clone the whole repository to "gh-pages" branch and enable github page on that branch. it automatically deploy everytime I push on gh-pages branch. but only the page with 15 links is published, everytime i click in a link, it goes 404. I try to access the sub-folder by typing {username}.github.io/{repo}/{subfoldername} but it doesn't work.

I tried to google and check out sub-module but it seems like over complicated and doesn't work for me.
How should i publish every sub folder on github-pages? is there any right tutorial that you could show me. Thank so much!!

Comment: You don't need submodules, but something's not right with your links in the parent HTML file. Which we need to see to be able to help.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thank for your comment. I actually fixed that: i just put index.html after the subfoldername/.                              
https://github.com/cozyGarage/Javascript30Challenge
you can check out from my github. But I have seen some of github-page that they don't have to include index.html in the url. Do you know, how can achieve that.

Comment: You can often just omit `index.html`, and the web server is going to return it anyway.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.